# How do I write a udev rule to persist an attribute on boot?

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, udev

I want to persist the value of `/sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/fn_lock` to be `1` after a reboot. After doing a lot of research, it seems that the right way to do this is to create a udev rule for it. So I ran `udevadm info -a -p /sys/devices/platform/lg-laptop/` which returns this:

```
looking at device '/devices/platform/lg-laptop':
    KERNEL=="lg-laptop"
    SUBSYSTEM=="platform"
    DRIVER=="lg-laptop"
    ATTR{battery_care_limit}=="0"
    ATTR{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTR{fan_mode}=="0"
    ATTR{fn_lock}=="0"
```

And I made a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-fnlock.rules` with the following content:

```
ACTION=="change", KERNEL=="lg-laptop", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", ATTRS{fn_lock}="1"
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect when I reboot. Is my syntax wrong, or am I misunderstanding how to set attributes with udev?

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for the rules file was:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="platform", DRIVER=="lg-laptop", ATTR{fn_lock}="1"
```

I think my mistake was probably `ATTRS{fn_lock}` instead of `ATTR{fn_lock}`, since the matching rules (ones with `==` operator) seem to be a bit flexible.

Comment: It will be easier to find, if set as accepted. Thank you for sharing the solution.